# Are "seldom" and "rarely" truly interchangeable?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

As per answer to [When do we use "rarely, hardly, seldom"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/when-do-we-use-rarely-hardly-seldom), the words "rarely" and "seldom" are synonyms and can be used interchangeably.

I wonder if this is really the case in spoken English. I am not talking about grammatical correctness, but common usage. As a non-native speaker, I find the following sentence to be odd in a casual setting:

> I seldom go to the movies these days.

I would prefer this one variant instead because it sounds less formal:

> I rarely go to the movies these days.

Can someone shed some light on whether my hunch is correct, whether the words are really interchangeable?

The reason I came up with this question is that I often hear other Germans prefer "seldom" over "rarely" because it sounds very close to the German "selten", so it's an obvious natural pick. On the other hand I only rarely hear the word in spoken English and I think I have never used it myself.

If I'm wrong in my assumption that the words have different nuances, I think it would help me to have a few example sentences that use the word "seldom" when used by native speakers in an everyday casual context.

Comment: I don't find _rarely_ 'less formal' than _seldom_. In informal speech it would be "I don't often go to the movies these days".

Comment: If the two words are used side by side, I would rank 'rarely' as the less frequent event. 'I seldom drink wine' - I might have a glass if you offered me one, vs.  'I rarely drink wine' -I might have a glass once a year. But used in isolation, interchangeable. (Native English).

Comment: Do you rarely hear "seldom" or seldom hear "rarely"?

Comment: Both are acceptable, and it is common for non-native English speakers to use English words cognate to those in their own language, as with *seldom/selten*.  I was once in a meeting between French and British engineers in English where the French asked the British to use longer English words in the hope they would be closer to the equivalent French words.

Comment: In spite of "Andy M's comment, some regard 'seldom' as equivalent to 'very rarely'.  But I wouldn't distinguish these words myself. _But_ the intensified 'very rarely'  and 'extremely rarely' and intensified/otherwise modified 'annoyingly rarely' etc are available, while 'extremely seldom' and 'annoyingly seldom' sound unnatural to my ears. Of course, adjectival 'seldom' (where it persists) cannot be substituted by 'rarely' ('It is seldom that a month passes by without my receiving several letters on this subject').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: To a first approximation, I'd say all your misgivings about "qualified" uses of ***seldom*** probably just stem from the fact that you don't hear or use it anywhere near as often as ***rarely***. If I compare the usage charts for ***I seldom / I rarely*** and ***I very seldom / I very rarely***, it seems to me we were just as likely to use the intensified version of ***seldom*** as we were to use the *unqualified* version, back when ***seldom*** was far more common than ***rarely***.

Comment: There are no exact synonyms.

Comment: Are any two words "truly interchangeable"?

Comment: Your first example (*I seldom go to the movies these days*) sounds odd to my American-English ears. I can't prove this and haven't researched it, but *seldom* would seem more likely with the passive voice: *The movies are seldom attended these days.*

Answer (score 2):

> As per answer to this question, the words "rarely" and "seldom" are synonyms and can be used interchangeably.

It is usually a mistake to think that two English words are true synonyms, i.e. interchangeable in all circumstances without alteration to the surrounding meaning.

What happens in dictionaries is that, rather than a definition of an entry, (which, for logical reasons, cannot be done by including the word itself) we have a close paraphrasing in various contexts.

The guidance is "If the word or phrase is different, then the meaning or nuance is different."

English has words from (i) Latin, (ii) Norman French, and (iii) Anglo-Saxon, respectively the language of the (i) educated, (ii) the ruling classes and (iii) the rest of us. Whereas, over 1,000 years has given some levelling among the three, it has by no means been 100% effective, and words introduced from one of the sources will usually have nuances of those who spoke them.

**Rare** is from the Latin - **Seldom** is from the Germanic.

Beyond this, like many English words, they are not univocal. Consider the meaning of **rarely** as (OED) **Thinly, scantily; sparsely.**

1797   *J. Bailey & G. Culley Gen. View Agric. Northumberland (new ed.) viii. 100*   They [sc. rich grazing pastures] are so **rarely** scattered, that few farms are so fortunate as to enjoy so desirable appendage.

And the completely different:

1797   *J. Bailey & G. Culley Gen. View Agric. Northumberland (new ed.) viii. 100*   They [sc. rich grazing pastures] are so **seldom** scattered, that few farms are so fortunate as to enjoy so desirable appendage.

Or

1982   *Harvard Stud. Classical Philol. 86 260*   These notes are very full for the first Eclogue and are scattered **rarely** in a few other Eclogues.

Whereas this has an entirely different meaning (or is wrong)

*These notes are very full for the first Eclogue and are scattered **seldom** in a few other Eclogues.

Then we have the meaning for **rarely** as (OED) **3. Unusually or remarkably well; finely, splendidly, excellently.**

1989   J. Picton & J. Mack Afr. Textiles v. 105   These cloths are both **rarely** woven and expensive.

Also: *1977   Daily Tel. 13 May 18*   George Daniels..was **rarely** honoured in Stockholm yesterday. The Stockholm Watch Guild awarded him its Victor Kullberg Medal, bestowed only three times before.

(Rarely (OED) -> **4. To an unusual degree; exceptionally, very.**)

"Seldom" is not going to work, is it?

Comment: "It is usually a mistake to think that two English words are true synonyms" That's so true, and it's frankly frustrating that dictionaries like Merriam-Webster keep abusing the tenuous concept of synonym, even in their definitions, let alone their thesaurus. The only way I could think of for any pair of words to be synonyms at all is for them to be dialectal equivalents, so that they're semantically "equal" in their own dialects, rather than being restricted to different registers in a single dialect. Like "rucksack" & "abseil" in British English vs "knapsack" & "rappel" in American English.

Comment: English abhors a synonym just as nature abhors a vacuum. If two words *have* ended up both being used in English with the same meaning (perhaps we borrowed different words from German and French for the same referent), native speakers will quickly find a way of meaningfully using them differently. It may not be a perfect example, but I think we got ***cow*** from German, and ***beef*** from French. But we never use the former for the meat (except Desperate Dan's "cow pie" :), and almost no-one today uses the latter (or its plural ***beeves***) to refer to the living animal(s).

Comment: But the poster is clearly not concerned with other meanings of the word rarely, but its use in a sense similar to "seldom". He is asking whether there are subtle nuances there. So although I agree with your "no true synonyms", I don't think this is an answer to the question.

Comment: @David: So far as I can see, OP isn't exactly asking whether the two words are ***semantically*** "equivalent" (a fairly meaningless concept, imho). He's asking whether they're ***freely interchangeable*** in any given context. And the main reason they're  ***not*** "equivalent" is the [massive shift in relative prevalence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+rarely%2CI+seldom&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3) over the past couple of centuries. For almost all *learners*, that's about the only relevant factor in terms of distinguishing the two words.

Comment: When I was a kid, a teacher commented that she would give some sort of bonus credit for a pair of perfect synonyms. I got the credit for "inter" and "inhume."

Comment: Almost all uses of the word 'synonym' are unqualified, so that the better definition is 'one of a set of 2 or more words interchangeable in certain contexts with no or negligible change in meaning / nuance' (which appears somewhere).

Comment: @Chaim — “inhume”? What language is that? (Doesn’t flag up on my phone. )

Comment: @David I'm afraid it's English. It's in the dictionary at the Merriam-Webster site. It's sort of like "inter."

Comment: @Chaim — I must admit I read "inter" as in "inter alia" (or Inter Milan), but still, you must have been a rather precocious child.

Comment: @David No doubt, I'm a marvel of unrealized potential. I think that the opposite, exhume, is more common, by the way.

Comment: @Chaim — Could possibly be US/UK usage, although the word is in my British Chambers. I have an old-fashioned English Grammar school education, and although a science student, did the Latin required for Oxford entry in my day. So I suspect it’s either antiquated or restricted to certain professions (legal?) in Britain. But perhaps we should just bury this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry for wording the question poorly, but David is right: I am aware that a word can have different meanings and that a synonym may not match all of them but only a subset. What I was looking for was what David wrote: Whether I could subsitute `rarely` with `seldom` in modern English or whether `seldom` would feel out of place because it's either gone out of fashion or would seem too formal in everyday speech. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Funny enough, your comment may point to what I was looking for: Your link offers insight into the general usage of the words, so I guess it would be incorrect assuming that `seldom` is going out of style in each and every of its meanings, but wouldn't it be an indicator that this might be the case for the "similar to rarely case"? I was wondering where my reaction at hearing fellow Germans use the word so much was coming from. My assumption was that it's just not used as often anymore in common English and the link could be an indicator that this might be true to some degree.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure that this question doesn’t suit ELL better — certainly we don’t supply examples for learners. I am also hesitant to base an answer “yes” purely on personal experience. However, as there is one answer “no” (the two are not interchangeable in this context) I’ll stick my neck out.

- *In the context of the sense in which the words are used in the two example sentences* I would say there is no difference in meaning between *seldom* and *rarely*.
- From my experience as a child having to learn the word at school, I would say that *seldom* is less used in conversation, and more used by educated people, especially in writing. However, difference in social group preference does not equate to difference in meaning for a word.

As @Greybeard states in his answer, there are *other* uses of the word *rarely* in which *seldom* does not work — but it does in going to the cinema (I mean movies).

**Footnote**
[A Google books ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rarely+go+out%2Cseldom+go+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) for “seldom go out” v. “rarely go out” (with inspection of the  books retrieved) suggests that *seldom* was more commonly used in written matter until the mid-twentieth century, when *rarely* started to increase in popularity.

Comment: Thank you, I am not aware at the line between ELU and ELL, sorry if this was the wrong place. Maybe I also phrased the question poorly, I was specifically interested in cases where one or the other would be perceived as a strange choice. Initially I thought using `seldom` instead of `rarely` was incorrect, something like a *false friend*, but that does not seem to be the case. So now I am searching for where my negative reaction towards the word came from. My only explanation is that I never really heard the word a lot in movies or conversation, so apparently it's just used less today.

Answer (score 1):

*Seldom* is oriented towards situations that are linear in time. It carries with it the sense of not-very-often, the viewpoint being to regard a series of events one-at-a-time.

*Rarely* doesn't automatically bring this to the table. It needs context. It is often used to mean *infrequently*, but can also be used in situations that don't involve time - *Electric cars rarely make economic sense*. I prefer *rarely* over *seldom* in the sense of improbable at any one instance in time, particularly when you are taking a global perspective on the set.

If you use *seldom* in the same sentence - *Electric cars seldom make economic sense* - it has the perspective of considering each case one-by-one, which happens over time, at least metaphorically.

Things that are inherently repetitive or sequential work well with *seldom* - *cooking eggs in the microwave seldom works well.*

While I didn't find this distinction stated in any dictionaries, I did find that the example uses, when listed side by side, did follow this pattern, with *seldom* always being used for an occasion-by-occasion treatment. Also there are answers on Quora and other sites that have made the same observations. But it's a pretty fine distinction, and with just a little context, *rarely* can cover *seldom's* uses.

Comment: I was exactly looking for nuances like this. As some commenters noted, there are no true synonyms, so I was looking for examples where one or the other would be more appropriate, even in nuances. What makes your answer very interesting is that you attempt an explanation about these nuances. The problem is that there may not be dependable sources to verify this claim. Could you provide some links to the results of your research? Otherwise I'll try to search for this discussion myself (although I initially did that before asking the question, but I may have missed something).